# Django FileField save the url instead of the path in the database

Tags: django

I have a FileField on my form.
I like the way it behaves, writes the file to MEDIA_ROOT, etc.
I'd like to change what it writes to the database.

If I look in the database I see the path.. `/home/user/media/path/to/file.txt` what I would like it to write is the URL path without the domain `/media/file.txt`
Is there an argument to pass into the ModelForm, or Model?
 
If not, which class do I override?

Seems like bad practice to write absolute path's to a database. I need to be able to dynamically change MEDIA_ROOT & MEDIA_URL. And possibly share this database with other non django applications that would only need the URL of the media.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a way to save the URL in the database, but you *can* save a relative path in the database. I suppose you have set `upload_to` to an absolute path. You can change that to a path relative to your `MEDIA_ROOT`, for example `upload_to="path/to/". See also the [official Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) on that matter.

Comment: I understand that approach, but I'd like the record to be '/media/path/to/file.txt' and the upload_to='path/to/'.

Comment: @sk1p's answer seems like the better option, otherwise you have the same problem with 'absoluteness' in the db except it's an absolute url rather than an absolute path... in other words if you had reason to change `MEDIA_URL` then your data would be broken, but doing it @sk1p's way any change is handled by `MEDIA_ROOT` & `MEDIA_URL` settings